# jsonstat.from_file() return error "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'"

Tags: json, python-2.7

I'm trying to parse a json-stat file using jsonstat.py (v 0.1.7) but am getting an error.

The code below is copied from the examples on github (https://github.com/26fe/jsonstat.py/tree/master/examples-notebooks):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import jsonstat

os.chdir(r'D:\Desktop\JSON_Stat')
url = 'http://www.cso.ie/StatbankServices/StatbankServices.svc/jsonservice/responseinstance/NQQ25'
file_name = "test02.json"
file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("..","JSON_Stat", "CSO", file_name))
```

I added this line to deal with non ascii characters in the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

this succesfully downloads the json file to my desktop:

```
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    print("using already downloaded file {}".format(file_path))
else:
    print("download file and storing on disk")
    jsonstat.download(url, file_path)
```

From here, I can load and pprint the data using the json module:

```
import json
import pprint as pp

with open(r"CSO\test02.json") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

pp.pprint(data)
```

... but when I try and use the jsonstat module (as specified in the examples) I get the error mentioned in the subject:

```
collection = jsonstat.from_file(r"D:\Desktop\JSON_Stat\CSO\test02.json")
collection
# abbreviated error message
--> 384 self.__pos2cat = self.__size * [None]
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

I understand what the error message itself means but, having studied the the dimensions.py module where it occurs, am stuck trying to understand why. I was able to run the sample OECD code without issue so perhaps the data itself is not formatted in the expected way, though the source site (http://www.cso.ie/webserviceclient/) states that the json-stat format is being used.

So, finally, my questions are: has anyone run into this error and resolved it? Has anyone succesfully used the jsonstat module to parse this specific data? Alternatively, any general advice towards troubleshooting this issue is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Can you fill an issue here https://github.com/26fe/jsonstat.py/issues? I have tried to reproduce the error but without luck. I don't use windows, but I think you can execute `jsonstat http://www.cso.ie/StatbankServices/StatbankServices.svc/jsonservice/responseinstance/NQQ25` on windows terminal and see what happen.

Comment: I forget that you can find help also into google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/json-stat

Comment: solved by author: [github](https://github.com/26fe/jsonstat.py/issues/1)